# c program started in gnome-terminal stops running

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal

My first posting, so learning this askubuntu posting system.  I'm trying to automate my Ubuntu 14.04LTS server using Ubuntu's Startup Applications.  I automatically start several bash scripts within gnome-terminal windows when the pc is restarted.  However my C program quits running after about 10 minutes to an hour when starting it via the Startup Applications.

Here is an example of a Startup Applications Command that works:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "notifyserial.sh; #!/bin/bash"
```

(works fine, scripts continue to run, monitoring processes, terminal window stays active)

My "c program" called  "serial" starts and is updating print statment like below:

```
   Command: 14 01 - Cashless Reader Enable

   Starting main loop

   ********************************************************************

   Started    **serial**    program at : Wed Sep 27 17:19:27 2017

   ********************************************************************
```

After about 10-20 minutes the program stops and this shows in yellow at the top of the terminal window:

```
The child process exited normally with status 139.
```

Within "Startup Applications" I have tried adding the following commands, reboot the computer, then wait and see if the "serial" program continues to run indefinitely, however it does not:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "sudo ./myprogram"
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -e  "sudo ./myprogram"
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "startserial.sh; #!/bin/bash" && DISPLAY=:0 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,shaded
```

When I have the terminal profile set to "Hold the terminal open" I get this:

```
The child process exited normally with status 139.
```

When I have the terminal profile set to "Exit the terminal" the terminal window disappears.

I tried putting the various commands in a bash script since my other scripts stay working indefinitely as they are supposed to.  I the bash script `startserial.sh`I tried each of these command lines individually rebooted and waited for the results:

```
#!/bin/bash
#gnome-terminal -e "/home/cpi-machine3/serial_ver2_machine3_75centair_3_95"  --window-with-profile-internal-id=b9dc7b22-e86b-4ab0-9cdd-4470e1ed6b9
#/home/cpi-machine3/serial
#gnome-terminal -x sh -c "sudo ./serial"
```

I have started this program with gnome terminal by opening terminal: clicking on terminal icon or by ctrl + alt + t and type:

```
sudo ./serial
```

Then press enter.
My program runs for weeks.  Gnome Terminal stays active showing all the print commands to the screen as I programmed.

My goal is to have c program, "serial" automatically start and keep running when the pc reboots from: 1. a power outage 2. I remotely reboot the pc with Teamviewer or 3. reboot through Gnome Schedule v2.2 on a recurring schedule.

Replies:

Tried this in terminal but it quit after about 20 minutes (same issue):

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "sudo /home/cpi-machine3/serial"
```

From the feed back I will try this command in bash script:

```
 gnome-terminal -x bash -c "sudo /home/cpi-machine3/serial"
```

In the upcoming terminal you're been asked for the root password and enter it, am I correct there?

Not now I typed a command and no longer need to enter the password.

Is your program meant to be run as root?

I don't know.  "serial" resides in my '/home' directory.  And I start it from there.  It does not run unless I use 'sudo'

is it meant to be a system service?  I'm not sure what that means.

This is a new issue:  I started my "serial" normally by opening a terminal window (clicking on the terminal icon) and now my program is ending. The command prompt appeared just like pressing ctrl + c to break out of my program.  This has not happened before, on either of my pc's running this program.

```
  Command: 14 01 - Cashless Reader Enable
  Starting main loop
  ********************************************************************
   Started    **serial**    program at : Wed Sep 27 17:44:11 2017

  ********************************************************************
  cpi-machine3@CPI-Machine3:~$
```

Comment: Is your program meant to be run as root? is it meant to be a system service? It's not quite clear what exactly you're trying to do from your question.

Comment: Well, if your process is exiting with status code 139, that is not normal. You should debug from there I think, to find out what's going on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this now as it's unclear what you're asking – you try to start `notifyserial.sh`, `myprogram`, `startserial` and `serial` and it's totally vague which is supposed to do what, as (plus) you provide no script content at all.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized my C program had an error causing it fail 10 minutes to an 1 hour after running. It was not the Terminal having issues. I am still unable to automatically start my C program in the Startup Applications program.  So I will do some more trouble shooting and post that question later if I need help.